# What type hint for heterogeneous variable length tuple in python?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I wrote some [python code](https://github.com/jburgy/blog/blob/master/fun/regexp.py#L221-L248) which constructs graphs as `dict` similar to standard lib's [graphlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/graphlib.html).  Graph construction maintains a stack of partial graphs with "exit" vertices.  Vertices are `tuple[Graph, str]` to mutate the node once the destination of that vertex becomes known.  Instead of creating a special-purpose type, the partial graph plus vertices are smushed together into a tuple, a little like lisp forms.  What type declaration can I use for these?  I tried the below but `"..." is only allowed as the second of two arguments`

```
from typing import Optional

Graph = dict[str, Optional["Graph"]]  # None is a terminal
GraphAndVertices = tuple[Graph, tuple[Graph, str], ...]
```

Comment: I don't quite get your actual type layout, can you include a small example? ``graphlib`` describes graphs as adjacency maps, which are completely different from your *recursive* ``Graph``, and doesn't use anything remotely similar to that ``tuple``  of yours.

Comment: Note that ``T, ...`` in tuples denotes a *variable* size tuple of *same-type* elements, whereas ``T1, T2`` in tuples denotes a *fixed* size tuple of *distinct-type* elements. You can construct something like ``tuple[T1, T2]`` or ``tuple[T1 | T2, ...]`` but ``tuple[T1, T2, ...]`` makes little sense.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It seems OP is trying to describe a variable-length tuple of the form `(A, B)` / `(A, B, B)` / `(A, B, B, B)` , ... I don't think that's something the tuple is equipped for...

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, I don't think the tuple type is equipped for that sort of annotation.

I think you might have a better time rewriting things to

```
from typing import Optional

Graph = dict[str, Optional["Graph"]]
GraphAndVertices = tuple[Graph, tuple[tuple[Graph, str], ...]]
```

i.e. keeping the "tail" in another variable-length tuple of graph/str pairs.

Comment: Thank you @akx.  I was reluctant to split `GraphAndVertices` to operate on it as a whole (using `__iadd__` to add vertices for example).  Ended up taking your suggestion one step further and kept graph and vertices completely separate, in two different variables, combining them only when strictly necessary.  Code readability improved as a result!

Answer (score 1):

This is now supported in Python 3.11 using the new type hints for Variadic Generics, specifically for unpacking unbounded tuples [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#unpacking-unbounded-tuple-types)

The type hint now could be written as
`GraphAndVertices = tuple[Graph, *tuple[Graph, str]]`